# Unable to fetch thumbnails using Dropbox core API - 401

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

I am able to successfully retrieve metadata using the Dropbox API using the following URL:

```
https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/mse
```

When I try to retrieve a thumbnail for a listed asset, I get a 401:

```
https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/thumbnails/dropbox/mse/modem_status.png?size=l
```

In both cases I am providing the access token in the header:

```
Authorization: Bearer 4JSL1tGWoVEAAAAAAAAAAUxNYpLbiYw-D8l3vqTKRKNBuGnezhps8j.....
```

I can't see what is missing here.

Comment: What's the body of the 401 response?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that an image is being returned - I was using POSTMAN to test the url and two urls show up in the log - the first returns a 200 with an image buffer containing JPEG data, and a subsequent url that fails with a 401. (the second GET does not contain the authorization header). However, I am at a loss as to how to make use of JPEG data returned from an XHR request - how am I supposed to create an `<img>` element this way? Isn't there something equivalent to `/media` which returns a public url that is valid for 4 hours?

Comment: Wow - I got it to work using `https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/thumbnails/dropbox/mse/modem_status.png?size=l&access_token=blahblahblah` !!

Comment: Be careful not to leak the access token to others though.